# How to change 2d coordinates from side view to top view

Tags: svg, 2d, coordinates

Now i am using svg tool to create 2d objects , but now i am able to see the side view . but i dont know how to write coordinates for top view . my coding is for side view as follows . how can i change this coordinates for top view . I tried a lot and i am search in google also but i am unable to find answer help me to do it

```
"bat": "m143.40468,206.20782c-0.49527,-8.51843 -1.60919,-23.17813 -13.91826,-16.10698c-5.69614,2.11977 -22.79842,7.51244 -14.5293,-3.62979c-4.53243,-11.10219 -22.97476,5.42294 -24.24419,-2.29205c9.91943,-10.64906 -4.7813,-22.35199 -15.17139,-14.80321c-6.39341,1.76166 -19.4276,12.91188 -21.9789,9.37552c5.93793,-7.52516 19.31312,-22.93167 3.18112,-27.55084c-17.5302,-3.97589 -32.93319,8.09392 -48.1771,14.68205c-4.57452,3.57106 -10.39707,2.94862 -4.70683,-2.99597c19.7419,-30.64111 50.72646,-53.70857 85.10566,-65.43076c8.33369,-2.70812 21.16511,-8.70424 21.41656,4.97536c5.15313,12.59007 8.81947,28.33097 22.08977,34.80917c15.28362,8.49702 4.32793,-24.52711 20.16156,-12.05241c6.66379,4.32207 20.92268,-3.91697 22.87737,0.71265c-3.88257,5.55579 -5.70456,15.41883 4.55382,10.3489c17.81406,-7.0078 30.89859,-22.70471 39.67026,-39.22318c9.16278,-1.3768 18.27335,5.56162 26.62798,9.24753c27.74529,15.70954 44.86571,45.39448 52.13728,75.65768c-7.5513,-4.24557 -14.87186,-12.828 -24.02185,-16.20273c-9.75534,-4.87419 -20.75789,-5.73363 -31.48114,-5.39867c-5.02554,5.98985 -7.99353,13.42558 -3.62529,20.86708c3.80284,14.25407 -12.13176,-4.90576 -17.88498,-6.20744c-10.74191,-7.67955 -21.03323,3.92213 -18.67635,14.82222c-2.42909,2.10051 -9.92085,-3.5218 -14.32263,-2.86926c-9.05026,-2.72606 -15.42468,1.20085 -9.97261,10.61331c-7.98315,-0.97417 -19.64474,-13.28291 -26.70493,-1.69363c-3.0779,2.89514 -4.66377,8.66307 -8.40561,10.34547z"
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG does is a 2D document format.  It does not support 3D objects or coordinates.